# How to make popup volume bar linear instead of pixely box?

Tags: sound, indicator, volume-control, appearance, indicator-sound

I used to have a nice sleek-looking linear popup volume slider bar like this:

[image]

Now I have a pixelly volume slider box whenever I change the volume on my keyboard:

[image]

How do I change my pop-up volume bar back to what it used to be?

Comment: Did you play around with MyUnity or a similar program?